# simple getServerSideProps doesn't working

Tags: next.js, getserversideprops

I'm trying to use getServerSideProps nextJS function but it just doesn't work. Just return undefined for my props...

```
export async function GetServerSideProps(context){
    var test = 3 
    return {
        props: {
            test
        }
    }
}
 
export default function Page(props){

    console.log(props.test)

    return (
        <div>
           {props.test}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your function name: `GetServerSideProps` ==> `getServerSideProps`. `getServerSideProps` function name needs to be camel cased, otherwise it's not picked up and executed by Next.js.